# Importing data to expression engine v1 from xml

Tags: xml, expressionengine

I want to import xml data as entries into a website running expression engine v1.7
Are there any extensions, modules, procedures etc. that facilitate this? 
Please note that I don't have any control over the xml data provided.

Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am the author of DataGrab that was mentioned in a previous answer.

I have a plugin for EE1 called XMLGrab that may be of help:

http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/xmlgrab

XMLGrab will allow you to import XML files into EE1 weblogs. It can be downloaded from:

https://bitbucket.org/ajweaver/xmlgrab/overview

with some brief instructions.

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest taking a look at DataGrab by Andrew Weaver. It allows for a number of different methods of importing including XML.

http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab

His support can be a little hit and miss at times, but he's generally fairly active in the EE community.

There's also Solspace Importer, which I believe does the same thing, though I have no personal experience of that one.

http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/importer/

Comment: For v1.x, it's not actually DataGrab; it's either CSVGrab or XMLGrab. (They used to be separate modules.) Andrew Weaver will likely be willing to provide you with an old copy though.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there are no addons for EE v1.7 currently being sold that will import XML data for you.

Solspace Importer and DataGrab both require EE2.x.

NOTE: Solspace Importer did previously work with EE1.x but they aren't selling it anymore. You might try emailing them to see if they will sell it to you directly.